# Export presentation on pdf format

Tags: php, pdf, google-drive-api, google-slides-api

I want to export google slide presentation en pdf format using g-slide api, I used this  Google api function:

```
$fileId = '1ZdR3L3qP4Bkq8noWLJHSr_iBau0DNT4Kli4SxNc2YEo';
$response = $driveService->files->export($fileId, 'application/pdf', array('alt' => 'media' ));
$content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

When I do `print_r($content)` I can see the pdf code. But how I can display the `$content` on pdf file, that can I saved on local machine ?.

Comment: I just want to confirm. Do you want to save the google slide file on your computer as a PDF file?

Comment: yes, that's it,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve the problem like that:

```
$driveService = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);
$response = $driveService->files->export($presentation_id, 'application/pdf', array('alt' => 'media' ));
$content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
$filename = str_replace(" ", "-", 'pdf_name.pdf');

file_put_contents($upload_dir['path'].'/'.$filename, $content);
```

`$upload_dir['path']` is a folder project path for me.